# saltstack dotnet install fails on windows minion

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to install applications on windows server 2012r2 minion. Namely I'm interested on MS management and .NET frameworks. I can install apps like winscp and firefox successfully, so basically it should work.

Install of .NET (dotnet.sls) gives me this:

```
# salt 'minion3' pkg.install dotnet
minion3:
    ----------
    dotnet:
        Unable to locate package dotnet
```

.sls points to MS download site, where the actual file can be downloaded.

On the minion side I've got:

```
2016-04-13 11:41:27 [salt.loaded.int.module.cmdmod][INFO    ] Executing command 'Powershell -NonInteractive "Import-Module ServerManager"' in directory 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile'
2016-04-13 11:41:28 [salt.loaded.int.module.win_pkg][ERROR   ] Unable to locate package dotnet
```

And asking for the available versions (pkg.available_version dotnet) gives me:

```
minion3:
    The minion function caused an exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\minion.py", line 1071, in _thread_return
        return_data = func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "c:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\modules\win_pkg.py", line 103, in latest_version
        latest_available = _get_latest_pkg_version(pkg_info)
      File "c:\salt\bin\lib\site-packages\salt\modules\win_pkg.py", line 1088, in _get_latest_pkg_version
        return sorted(pkginfo, cmp=_reverse_cmp_pkg_versions).pop()
    IndexError: pop from empty list
```

None of the other state files I've tried do not give above errors.

So, what is going on and how to correct this?

Comment: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/windows/windows-package-manager.html
"The SLS files used to install Windows packages are not distributed by default with Salt.".  Please go through the document to install it :-D